# How to open Explorer window to show another PC's directory using command line

Tags: windows, command-line, windows-explorer

I want to make a shortcut/batch file to **prompt for username/password** and then for a **specific directory to be opened in Windows Explorer.** I'm using Windows XP.

The following prompts for the other PC's username/password and opens explorer to show Printers and Faxes/Scheduled Tasks (nearly there but not quite):

```
explorer.exe /e,/root,"\\150.204.104.25"
```

What I want to do is something like:

```
explorer.exe /e,/root,"\\150.204.216.26\",/select,"\\150.204.216.26\c$"
```

Unfortunately, all this does is show my own PC's C: drive.

Any ideas if this is possible (and if so where I'm going wrong)? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could map the other directory to a drive letter, and then open it in explorer. 
I don't recommend that you link to c:\, but if you need to...

LinkToFolder.bat (username and password need to be replaced with your username and password)

```
net use x: \\150.204.216.26\c$ password /USER:username
explorer x:\
```

Comment: Rather than hard code the "x:" see this question for getting the next available drive letter:
http://superuser.com/questions/58572/how-can-i-extract-the-drive-letter-for-a-new-mapped-drive-in-a-bat

Comment: +1 for @seanyboy and +1 for @Neal - used both to find the solution - thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will work for you. It'll open your directory and show it as the root:

```
explorer.exe /e, /root, \\150.204.216.26\c$
```

Answer (score 0):

You can map a random drive letter and get it:

```
@echo off
for /f "tokens=2 delims= " %%a in ('net use * \\server\share ^| find "is now connected"') do set "drive=%%a"
explorer %drive%
```